# How to make a hub motor Ebike faster?

Tags: electric-bike, speed

I built an Ebike with a 1000w hub motor, 1000w motor controller and 48v battery. With this setup and a cheap steel frame 26 inch wheel bike I can get a 34.6 mph top speed on flat ground. I just bought a new motor controller that can do peak 3000 watts and a new 52v battery and I'm seeing approx 1mph speed increase. I do get a lot more acceleration (which feels amazing) but not a much higher top speed. Any thoughts on what I can do to increase the top speed more. 72v battery? Do I need a new hub motor/should I switch to something with gears? Should I try and get a bike with larger wheels? Start installing fairings for more aero?

I can tweak settings on the motor controller as it plugs into my laptop via usb and I have everything pretty much maxed (45 amps, no speed limiter).

I do pedal, but my gears are not quite large/small enough for that to do anything but increase my acceleration.

I'm hoping to get around 45mph so I can hit the speed limit on the two lane roads near my house with no bike lanes.

Comment: Have you considered buying a motorcycle?

Comment: Seriously. What you're building there really shouldn't be considered a bicycle any more.

Comment: You're missing the point of riding a bike if you just sit on a motorised bike.  The point of electric assist is that it assists you, not replaces your effort.  Locally, 300W is the maximum permitted assist, you're 3x over that and would need to register and warrant your bike, and get it certified as a one-off custom build, and need a motorbike endorsement on your drivers licence.  And a registration plate on your vehicle, ride in traffic with the cars, be excluded from all bike paths, lanes, and facilities.

Comment: @Criggie I do pedal in addition to using the motor assist, although I do think you are right though, it probably should be classified as a motorbike. I don't think it is technically legal where I live but it is way cheaper than a car and my commute takes the same time as it would to drive.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is not about bicycles

Comment: @ojs now that Vespa make electric motorbikes, it looks quite tempting (headline specs: 3.6kW for 70km/h).  Probably expensive though, and may require a licence - as opposed to this contraption which is almost certainly illegal regardless of paperwork.  Guessing at a US location (not many places use miles, and 45mph limits aren't seen in the UK) [it's too fast](https://quietkat.com/pages/united-states-electric-bike-regulations-guide) and licensing might be needed too

Comment: @ChrisH Vespa is really catching up here, the market is already full of scary looking Chinese electric scooters that cost less than regular E-bikes

Comment: @ojs I see there are now some that are road legal in the UK.  While that's not directly a mark of quality it does at least mean certain safety features are present.  In some ways they look quite nice (even if [this](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=15396c02#T=S&C=5&O={%22color%22:5,%22iconly%22:0}) was clearly the design reference for some of them)

Comment: Voting to reopen.  I might not be keen on the idea myself, but we're talking about a bike frame and a motor sold for use on e-bikes (even if a rather large one).

Comment: @ChrisH its a good question about a bad idea.  If it were deleted/hidden, future readers wouldn't get to see all the reasoning.

Comment: Exactly @Criggie - your answer and many comments both address the major downsides and give some ideas for more realistic e-bike conversions. I have an idea something similar has come up before. I wonder if we need one Q&A on the topic of overpowered e-bikes, then most others can be duplicates. I'll have a look when I'm at the PC

Comment: ... This would be a more appropriate target than any I can find - possibly the others have been deleted after being closed

Comment: That's five separate users who have voted to re-open.    Check out https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1402/on-topic-ebikes-are-on-topic-for-bicycles-se for the historical thoughts about ebikes and their on/off-topicness - in short the bike bits are on-topic, electronics specific questions should go to EE.SE.

Comment: I feel that this was closed for good reasons. On many Stack Exchange sites we do not help people to break the law. 45 miles/h is well above the legal limit where I live, even when you have a moped aproved and insured e-bike. Not voting to close (as re-opened recently) but if I were a mod here I would close it.

Comment: @Willeke it's illegal on public roads in many (most) jurisdictions, rather than absolutely illegal, so not totally clear cut

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's really not in the spirit of cycling.

Answer (score 5):

According to this bicycle speed estimator you should reach about ~50km/h (30mph) with 1kW of motor power. If you can achieve a constant 3kW output power (requires a suitable motor, controller *and* battery) you should be able to reach ~70km/h (45mph).

You can play with the calculator/estimator yourself to see how changing various parameters (e.g. weight, using a more aerodynamic type of bike etc.) affects speed. For example changing to a road bike would allow you to do ~60km/h with 1kW of input power.

If you have a good acceleration but bad top speed you might want to play around with the gear ratios. Maybe your motor is getting close to its maximum RPM.

http://www.kreuzotter.de/english/espeed.htm

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is a very useful tool!

Comment: Just changing the tyres to medium-wide high pressure slicks gets you about 5% faster, but compared to flat bars, riding in the drops of a road bike is worth 16% (same tyres) - whether leg- or electric-powered, aero is the key for speed

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're in the area of marginal gains.  Every little change will help, not a lot, but combined should add some top-end speed.

- a 26" steel bike is going to be not aero, and will have a good amount of weight.  Replace the frame with a road bike or TT bike frame.
- 26" wheels are going to be wider, which is not aero.  Also the wider tyres weigh more.  You would ideally change to 622 road wheels with deep section rims and narrower tyres with a smooth tread.
- A disk rear wheel can help with aero, but side winds and truck draughts can unexpectedly push you across the road in an instant.  A front disk wheel should only be used indoors.
- fairings do help, but then they add weight too which needs to be balanced out
- Clothing - consider a skin suit and aero helmet.  Both of which are more aero than regular clothes and no-helmet.   Aero clothing is very thin, so offers no protection in a collision like motorbike leathers would provide.
- Battery weight - if you can decrease the battery size you drop the weight meaning there's less mass to accelerate.  However this reduces your range too.
- Rider weight - you can probably loose some weight from your body, and carry less stuff.

An increase in wheel size will lower your torque while increasing your top-end speed.  Downside is it will take longer to accelerate, and this rewards a straight line while penalising a route with turns.

---

- Your battery can only dump so much power at once.  Drawing more than its rated C load will decrease its lifespan and empty it faster.
- Your motor controller can only handle a certain amount of current.  Too much and it overheats.  Cooling can help here, but that wastes power which could be pushing you down the road.
- Your motor is *probably* the most robust part - they tend to be quite overbuilt - it may be possiblke to put 1500W through a 1000W motor, but the parts before it (controller, battery) will suffer.

Ultimately you're not riding a bicycle, you're on an electric motorbike.  They're related, after all motorbikes grew out of bicycles originally, but consider that an e-bike is an assistance, not a replacement for the rider's input.

Since implementing most/all the ideas above would replace everything, **you're probably better buying a motorbike and keep the bicycle separate.**

Comment: Hehe, your comment got me thinking - My great grandfather built the [first motorbike in New Zealand](https://bsaoc.co.nz/new-zealands-first-successful-motorcycle/) by bolting a motor to a pushbike. He rode it from Christchurch as far south as Dunedin (360km/220miles). I now recall the story, and thought "is this building E-Motorbikes people are doing is merely repeating history?"  (The Op could look at the at the 120 year old picture for inspiration how to make his bike go faster)

Comment: I'm running 2300 watts on my 1000 watt motor and it gets a little warm, but I was hoping that literally doubling my power would do a little more to my top speed. My motor controller is rated for 45A at 72Volts and right now I'm only running 52.

Comment: I wear either a full face mtn bike helmet or a motorcycle helmet with face shield (depending on temperature/rain/snow). I don't trust an aero helmet to save my face if I fall

Comment: @10Replies okay - I'd suggest you look at tyre width/tread first.  You could get some 26" smooth commuter tyres, I know Continental makes the "Grand Prix"  And uprate your brakes+pads !   While stopping doesn't help you go faster, it does help with your confidence.   And add decent lighting too - You need to Be Seen.

Comment: I would recommend taking a moment to think why motorcycles have the heavy tires and truss frames that they have before bolting a motor to a time trial bike.

Comment: I'd be more concerned with aero than weight, and use something sturdy like a steel touring or gravel frame (also allowing you to avoid really skinny tyres) then think about fairings.  Most of all I'd be concerned with staying away from it though, and I've got over 70km/h descending with no motor.

Comment: But If you're putting the best part of 40A through your cables, how fat are they? Do they get warm on a long run?  Cable length should also be minimise to reduce resistance.  Motor performance is also optimised for certain rotation rates, so you may be running up against limits there too

Comment: BTW 26" wheels aren't necessarily wide - they're used on small road bikes as well as many other things. Also I've fitted 28mm slicks to a hardtail used for commuting

Comment: Lighting - at that speed you need to see potholes in plenty of time - you'll need front lights that do a good job of illuminating the road well ahead, but a better beam shape than trail lights.  Choose wisely

Comment: @ChrisH I have two "3600 lumen" (probably not actually this bright but that is what the spec sheet states) ofroading lights mounted to the fork and led turn signals/brake lights

Comment: The problem with many offroading lights is often that most of the light ends up in the wrong place - not helping you, and making things worse for others.  Very few over about 1200 lumen have much in the way of beam-shaping optics, so they do more to light up the insides of oncoming cars than the road.  Hopefully yours are better, because they're claimed to be 2-3x as bright as car headlights

Comment: @Criggie TT frame? Aero helmet?  With a 1,000+W motor?  TT bikes are difficult enough to control for seasoned cyclists familiar with them.  That sounds dangerous.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Absolutely this sounds like a dangerous bike already.   I don't think any of this is a good idea overall.  But bad ideas still deserve to be shown, to light the way for future readers.

Comment: Even without a motor time trial bikes are ridden at >45km/h all the time. Which is already quite suicidal when you consider the side wind vulnerability and the inability to brake from the tucked position.

Comment: @Michael I'm not a TTer and I can't get that quick on the flat with the clip-ons on my tourer - but 35-40km/h is certainly scary when you're away from the brakes.  In a TT event at least other road users (if any) are normally warned, but not for training runs of course.

Answer (score -3):

I have a mate that puts small motorbike cogs on not push bike gears to get taller gearing  and he eats 50 KLM pH on a 1500 battery and says up battery one size and 70 KLM easy   but it's mainly the gearing
He has one but vertualy a motor bike 150 klph

Comment: What's "KLM"?  What does "up battery one size" mean?  (numbers)  What is the resulting gearing?  Please give a complete answer.